# How to set rake task for delete worker using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've got worker which deletes all admin logs older than 1 year. I want it run once a day using `gem whenever` as a rake task however I'm not follow the whole logic of rake tasks. I was trying to follow this article https://medium.com/@sampatbadhe/rake-task-invoke-or-execute-419cd689c3bd how ever the big question is should I move my worker to rake file or I can I refer directly to the file where this worker is?

my worker below:

```
class AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

      def perform
        expired_logs = AdminPanelLog.where('created_at < ?', 1.year.ago).select(:id)
        expired_logs.find_in_batches do |logs_batch|
          AdminPanelLog.where(id: logs_batch.map(&:id)).delete_all
        end
      end
    end
```

As far I understand my `schedule.rb` in `whenever gem` should be like below:

```
every 24.hours do
  rake 'myproject:AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a worker, not a rake task, so you can do it with

```
every 24.hours, at: '0:00am' do
 runner 'AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker.perform_async'
end
```

Comment: since you're not passing arguments, you can just call `.perform_async` without parens.